# Udp multicast swift

Tags: swift, server, udp, cloud, multicast

I am working in a new project, I am struggling with a problem with swift, I achieve to receive udp messages in localhost with NWConnection and NWListener, but I need to receive that messages from a cloud server, so I try with NWConnectionGroup and NWMulticastGroup, the reason is because I need that the streaming messages reach many users not necessary in the same wifi point, I can't use unicast because the project wouldn't be viable for the cost, I need to send one message from the server that reach multiple users in different locations, I use the simulator only so I don't need entitlement at the moment, is the class NWConnectionGroup and NWMulticastGroup the correct way for that? there are another options ? where I can find more documentation ? Because I can achieve the connection with udp multicast, thank

I try to find solution to udp multicsst connection in swift language